# fabric can `get`, but can't `run`

Tags: python, python-2.7, sftp, fabric

I'm using python2.7 and fabric to connect to an sftp server.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
from fabric.api import env, get, run
env.key_filename = '/path/to/keyfile'
env.host_string = 'host.string'
env.user = 'user'
```

At this point, `get('filename')` successfully downloads a file from the sftp server. But `run('ls')` gives me:

```
[host.string] run: ls
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/network.py", line 647, in host_prompting_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 1054, in run
    shell_escape=shell_escape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 923, in _run_command
    stderr=stderr, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 764, in _execute
    channel.get_pty(width=cols, height=rows)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 60, in _check
    return func(self, *args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 177, in get_pty
    self._wait_for_event()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 1086, in _wait_for_event
    raise e
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Channel closed.
```

When I manually log into the sftp server, using the same creds, I can `ls` just fine.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can you log into the server in a SSH shell? FTP is not really relevant for Fabric.

Comment: How are you executing this? Is it a task in your fabfile.py, and are you running `fab taskname` from the command line?

Comment: @HåkenLid I am running the commands in the python shell. 

I don't have SSH access.

Comment: You can't use Fabric without ssh access. And the methods `get` etc. imported from fabric will not work as expected unless run in the context of the `fab` command. I'm surprised that `get()` doesn't fail as well.

Comment: You may have SFTP only enabled on the server. This would explain why `get()` (which works with SFTP) while `ls()` does not.